# When does the slash in a Linux path need to be outside quotes in a bash script

Tags: bash, tilde-expansion

Why does the first expansion not work, yet the second does?

I know tilde has to be expanded outside quotes but the slash also had to be outside, unexpectedly.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls ~"/Documents/bashscripts/test.sh"
ls ~/"Documents/bashscripts/test.sh"
```

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate. The other question is about the entire string being quoted (so the shell doesn't attempt to expand the tilde at all). This question is about quoting the string *after* the tilde, and the shell has to interpret that. It's definitely not the same.

Comment: Funny.  It seems that another question mentioning the path as `~/"Documents/foo.sh" wouldn't be a duplicate too as the path is different.  Good to see a _novell_ question being asked and answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a subtlety in how [tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) works. In the second case, the tilde-followed-by-slash is expanded to the home directory of the current user. In the first case, the tilde-followed-by-quoted-word is attempted to be expanded to the home directory of the user named "/Documents/bashscripts/test.sh". From the manpage, *Tilde Expansion* section:

> …all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash are considered a tilde-prefix. If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name. …